# How do i print in process_request scrapy?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy

I'm a beginner at scrapy and I want to print something in function `process_request` but the problem is can't see it when looking at logs of scrapy

Code inside `middlewares.py > process_request`

```
        referr = random.choice(refreerr_list)
        print(referr)
        request.header['rtt'] = random.choice(rtt)
        request.header['sec-ch-viewport-width'] = random.choice(width_list)
        request.header['sec-ch-device-memory'] = random.choice(memory_list)
        request.header['device-memory'] = random.choice(memory_list)
        request.header['referer'] = referr
        request.header['cookie'] = 'sessi...'
        
        print(self._requests_count)

        
        self._requests_count += 1
        if self._requests_count > 500:
            self._requests_count = 0
            ip_changer.get_new_ip()


        print(f"thitshtisih {self._requests_count}")
```

As this I'm searching for `thitshtisih` but i can't able to see in terminal log.

I have tried this one also `spider.logger.info('Requestingsssssss %...` But same not found in code

This is how does the log looks like:

```
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.1 started (bot: amazonasin)
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.0.0, libxml2 2.9.4, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.4.0, Python 3.10.4 (v3.10.4:9d38120e33, Mar 23 2022, 17:29:05) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022), cryptography 37.0.2, Platform macOS-10.14.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 80,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 40,
 'BOT_NAME': 'amazonasin',
 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8-sig',
 'LOG_FILE': 'filename.log',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'amazonasin.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['amazonasin.spiders']}
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: a03baa23ca473ca6
2022-07-17 07:02:47 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2022-07-17 07:02:48 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Android
2022-07-17 07:02:48 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
2022-07-17 07:02:48 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
2022-07-17 07:02:48 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None

2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedDeviceType] Family: Other, Brand: None, Model: None
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy_user_agents.user_agent_picker] WARNING: [UnsupportedBrowserType] Family: Zune
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 ...
2022-07-17 07:02:50 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 4706293872 on /Users/adarshraj/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.4.final__3.10__22a438__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4706293872 acquired on /Users/adarshraj/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.4.final__3.10__22a438__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 4706293872 on /Users/adarshraj/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.4.final__3.10__22a438__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4706293872 released on /Users/adarshraj/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.4.final__3.10__22a438__tldextract-3.3.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07NP5TZRF> (referer: None)
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
2022-07-17 07:02:53 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07NP5TZRF>
{'brand': 'A M D',
 'isbn': 'B07NP5TZRF',
 'mainLink': 'https://www.amazon.com/FX-8350-8-Core-Socket-Processor-Thermal/dp/B07NP5TZRF',
 'permalink': 'FX-8350-8-Core-Socket-Processor-Thermal',
 'price': '$130.00'}
2022-07-17 07:03:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010T6CG7E> (referer: None)
2022-07-17 07:03:30 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
2022-07-17 07:03:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010T6CG7E>
{'brand': 'Intel',
 'isbn': 'B010T6CG7E',
 'mainLink': 'https://www.amazon.com/Intel-I5-6400-FC-LGA14C-Processor-BX80662I56400/dp/B010T6CG7E',
 'permalink': 'Intel-I5-6400-FC-LGA14C-Processor-BX80662I56400',
 'price': '$183.0'}
2022-07-17 07:03:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/dp/B083RM87F2> (referer: None)
2022-07-17 07:03:43 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
2022-07-17 07:03:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/dp/B083RM87F2>
{'brand': 'AMD',
 'isbn': 'B083RM87F2',
 'mainLink': 'https://www.amazon.com/AMD-3200MHZ-SYSTEM-COMPONENTS-PROCESSORS/dp/B083RM87F2',
 'permalink': 'AMD-3200MHZ-SYSTEM-COMPONENTS-PROCESSORS',
 'price': '$799.95'}
2022-07-17 07:03:50 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3 pages (at 3 pages/min), scraped 3 items (at 3 items/min)
2022-07-17 07:03:52 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force 
2022-07-17 07:03:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
2022-07-17 07:03:52 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Received SIGINT twice, forcing unclean shutdown
```

Comment: `scrapy crawl {name}`

Comment: Nope this is also not working

Comment: This is also not even working :/ one thing more in my request.header i have set referer but it showing none does middlewares not working or how do i setup it? 
as it is shoing `(referer: None)``` ``` crawled 200```

Comment: Thanks but fortunately I have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_links(self, link):
    for link in links:
        #1
        if 'foo' in link.text:
            continue  # skip all links that have "foo" in their text
        yield link 
        #2
        link.url = link.url + '/'  # fix url to avoid unnecessary redirection
        yield link
```

Comment: This is not answer i'm loking for?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.